# Set all values of a column in a multidimensional array

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following code that adds zero to values of a specific row in a multidimensional array:

```
def self.zero_row(matrix, row_index)
    matrix[row_index].each_with_index do |item, index|
      matrix[row_index][index] = 0
    end
    return matrix
end
```

I am wondering how I would go in order to make zeros all the values given a specific column_index.

```
def self.zero_column(matrix, col_index)
  #..
end
```

Comment: sawa, how do you structure a matrix within a flat array?

Comment: I moved my comments to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

To follow the same pattern as your other method you could do something like this:

```
def self.zero_column(matrix, col_index)
  matrix.each_with_index do |item, row_index|
    matrix[row_index][col_index] = 0
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Would this fit the bill?

```
def self.zero_column(matrix, col_index)
  matrix = matrix.transpose
  matrix[col_index].map!{0}
  matrix.transpose
end
```

Similarly, you could simplify your `zero_row` method

```
def self.zero_row(matrix, row_index)
  matrix[row_index].map!{0}
  matrix
end
```

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of `matrix[col_index] = [0]*matrix[0].size`, but `map!{0}` is definitely nicer. I'd think the use of `transpose` would be fine as long as the matrix is not too large, but @Alex's solution would be more efficient for larger matrices (even though `transpose` is coded in C).  Make sense?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I was thinking that the C coding for the internals of `transpose` and `map!` would trump explicitly iterating in the Ruby interpreter. At some point I should benchmark it and find out, just don't have time right now.  I fully expect that a `zero_row` implementation based on `map!` should be a winner over the iterated version.

Comment: @CarySwoveland And the benchmark results are in - for a 100x100 matrix, the map-based version of `zero_row` is twice as fast, but the double transpose in `zero_column` makes it 30 times as slow.

Comment: pjs, thanks for doing that.  It makes sense, and of course the factor of 30 for `zero_column` will increase with the size of the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to deal with columns frequently, then I would say it is a design flaw to use a nested array. Nesting array has almost no benefit, and just makes things complicated. You should better have a flat array. It is much easier to manipulate columns equally as rows with flat arrays.

If you want a 3 by 2 matrix, then you can initialize it simply as an array with the length 3 * 2 like:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Then, you can refer to the second column (index 1) or row as respectively:

```
a.select.with_index{|_, i| i % 2 == 1} # => [2, 4, 6]
a.select.with_index{|_, i| i / 2 == 1} # => [3, 4]
```

Rewriting all values of that column or row to `0` would be respectively:

```
a.each_index{|i| a[i] = 0 if i % 2 == 1} # => a: [1, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0]
```

or

```
a.each_index{|i| a[i] = 0 if i / 2 == 1} # => a: [1, 2, 0, 0, 5, 6]
```

Switching between an operation on a column and another on a row would be a matter of switching between `%` and `/`; you can see symmetry/consistency. If you need to keep the information regarding column length `2` within the array, then just assign it as an instance variable of that array.